# regarding asp.net regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a textbox and i am using a regular expression in asp.net and i want my user to enter in this format
cat10
as cat followed by numbers
so what should be my regular expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
cat\d+
```

Where the literal `cat` is followed by one or more numerals.

A good resource for regular expressions is http://regular-expressions.info